# Does a non deterministic turing machine solves a non deterministic algorithm in polynomial time

Tags: algorithm, polynomials, turing-machines, non-deterministic

Can a non deterministic turing machine solve a non deterministic algorithm in polynomial time with good guessing. And if yes why or how? Also if not why not?

Comment: It depends on the algorithm, it can *by definition* be done for the class of algorithms that run in polynomial time on a non-deterministic Turing machine. That's not interesting at all, just a tautology.

Comment: Let say the Algorithm can decide if a set of 1-Clausal is unattainable in time O(n^3*log(n)). Does that mean that the Algorithm can be solved in Polynomial time with a non deterministic turing machine. I mena it work in Polynomial time then it also should bepossible for a non det turing machine, but i need to know why it is so? In my example it is a Unification algorithm.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a theoretical Computer Science question.